# Code stops executing after opening browser through webdriver using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have been trying to open multiple browser windows in internet explorer using webdriver in selenium. Once it reaches the get(url) line, it just halts there and eventually times out. I've added a print line, which does not execute. I've tried various methods and the one below is the Ie version of code I used to open multiple tabs in Chrome. Even if I remove the first 3 lines, it still only goes up to opening google.com. I've looked googled this issue and looked through other posts but nothing has helped. Would really appreciate any advice, thanks!

```
options = webdriver.IeOptions()
options.add_additional_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Ie(options = options, executable_path=r'blahblah\IEDriverServer.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com")
print("syrfgf")
driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tab2');")
driver.switch_to.window("tab2")
driver.get("http://yahoo.com")
```

Comment: Try changing http://google.com -> https://www.google.com?

Comment: May be `https://www.google.com`?

Comment: it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the *url* you have provided:

```
http://google.com
```

with a proper [url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) as follows:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

Which should be represented as per the syntax diagram as follows:

[image: url syntax]

Comment: I have tried doing that, and it's still doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://github.com")
    
signin_link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")
signin_link.click()
time.sleep(1)

user = driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_field")
user.send_keys("X")

passw = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
passw.send_keys("X")

passw.submit()

time.sleep(5)

driver.close()
```

I had this issue and writing this code seems to have made it work flawlessly. Adjust the sleep time as you want it. Putting my chromedriver.exe into my project folder also helped with some errors